# search for a particular string in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 5000 rows in my notepad++. All rows have around 5000 rows like below:

```
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_000134260_06232019024054_Batch.pdf"
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_00000765_06298765454111_Batch.pdf"

"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_000134876_06232019456054_Batch.pdf"
```

I need to search for a number after 2019_ till I get another underscore so in other words I need to look for a number that is shown by xxxxxxxxx

```
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_xxxxxxxxx_06232019024054_Batch.pdf"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is it not enough just to search (`Ctrl`+`F`)  for a specific number e.g. `2019_00000765_` ?

Comment: Do you need to also replace this number?

Comment: Is `xxxxxxxxx` always going to be a bunch of digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `2019_\K\d+`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
2019_       # literally 2019_
\K          # forget all we have seen until this posiiton
\d+         # 1 or more digits
```

**Screen capture:**[image]

Comment: I like this but it fails to meet "I need to search for a number after 2019_ **till I get another underscore**"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Just replace `\d+` with `[^_]+` (i.e. `2019_\K[^_]+`

Answer (score 1):

For the search you can use:

```
\\2019_(\d+)_
```

If the content between the two underscores is not always a digit then this would work:

```
\\2019_([^_]+)_
```

---

If you need to replace it with something then use this in the "Replace with" field:

```
\\2019_ReplacementGoesHere_
```

and it would produce:

```
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_ReplacementGoesHere_06232019024054_Batch.pdf"
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_ReplacementGoesHere_06298765454111_Batch.pdf"
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_ReplacementGoesHere_06232019456054_Batch.pdf"
```

---

If you need to append something to the matches then access the matches with `$1`

```
\\2019_$1AppendMe_
```

and it would produce:

```
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_000134260AppendMe_06232019024054_Batch.pdf"
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_00000765AppendMe_06298765454111_Batch.pdf"
"\\PTMS-P-FS01.test.pcl\PTMS-RPTFiles\Batch\1037057\2019_000134876AppendMe_06232019456054_Batch.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for replacing the number:

`ctrl+f` -> "Replace" tab

Make sure to tick "Regular expression" in "Search Mode"

`Find what: 2019_([0-9]*)`

`Replace with: 2019_\1`

That example won't change the text as it overwrites value with exactly the same value but you can modify it for your purposes.

It uses regular expression to find the list of numbers after the string "2019_" and captures these numbers in a group. Then replaces every match with the corresponding capture group with attached "2019_" string to it - so it basically means "replace with exactly the same value" in this case (for more info on how to use captured groups see for instance [this](https://superuser.com/questions/162757/replace-with-same-expressions-in-notepad) post)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if we might have different inputs, I guess this expression

```
\\\d+\\2019_\K(\d+)_\d+_[^.]+\.pdf\K
```

has more than enough boundaries to return those desired digits, or maybe these simple ones:

```
2019_(\d+)
```

---

```
\\\d{4}_(\d+)
```

would work just fine.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nx0FJs/1/), if you wish to explore further or simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Nx0FJs/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: If you are going for the match in the group, I think you can omit `\K` and still have the group.